# Missing table elements in watch window of zerobrane studio

Tags: zerobrane, watch-window

I am new to using zerobrane studio. In the watch window the table elements "expression" and "value" are missing. Only a blank window is shown. How to add the two heading columns: "expression" and "value" in the watch window of zerobrane studio so as to make it work like the "normal" watch window shown in all the documentations of zerobrane studio.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the IDE provides the Watch window that supports expanding of table values and don't have `Expression` and `Value` headers (as it no longer presents the results in columns). These headers were present in earlier versions, but the UI was redesigned in version 0.80.